# Поиск файла по неполному имени в множестве

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть множество. В нем хранятся пути к файлам.

```
name = {
    'Migrations\\840_ELCODATA_Update_sp__MaturityGateControl_2to3.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_MOD_to_be_certified.sql',
    'Migrations\\BITE_index_report .sql',
    'Migrations\\RD2062_updateSP_sp_INSERT_ALERTS_FOR_RELEASED.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_SB_to_be_certified.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_UMO_Follow_up.sql',
    'Migrations\\10_1.20_correct_t_feature.sql',
    'Migrations\\20090604_A380_UpdateEDD.sql',
    'Migrations\\100_1-23_MAFU_CR_Data_migration.sql',
    'Migrations\\300_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3.sql',
    'Migrations\\740_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3_PCD.sql',
    'Migrations\\110_1-29_MAFU_addAttribute_TypeRFC.sql',
    'Migrations\\915_ELCODATA_spmg2to3.sql',
    'Migrations\\12-checker attributes.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_Export_the_Last_MoM.sql',
    'Migrations\\150_1-28_MAFU_Delete_permission_old_date_fields.sql',
    'Migrations\\141_EQPT_Attribute_updateInfobase.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_SB_certified.sql',
    'Migrations\\100_1-28_MAFU_AlterTable.sql',
    'Migrations\\MAFU_Forecast_Date_History_for_MP.sql',
    'Migrations\\20080214_EQT_DataMigration.sql'
}
```

Допустим я не знаю полного имени файла, а знаю часть имени, к примеру History, ввожу в строку часть имени файла и циклом прохожу, который должен выдать все файлы у которых есть данная строка. Как лучше всего реализовать поиск? Модуль glob подходит для решение данной задачи ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) используется для поиска файлов и директорий в файловой системе. Для поиска по строкам `glob` не приспособлен.

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями (`RegEx`), если я правильно понял задачу:

```
In [56]: import re

In [57]: name
Out[57]:
{'Migrations\\100_1-23_MAFU_CR_Data_migration.sql',
 'Migrations\\100_1-28_MAFU_AlterTable.sql',
 'Migrations\\10_1.20_correct_t_feature.sql',
 'Migrations\\110_1-29_MAFU_addAttribute_TypeRFC.sql',
 'Migrations\\12-checker attributes.sql',
 'Migrations\\141_EQPT_Attribute_updateInfobase.sql',
 'Migrations\\150_1-28_MAFU_Delete_permission_old_date_fields.sql',
 'Migrations\\20080214_EQT_DataMigration.sql',
 'Migrations\\20090604_A380_UpdateEDD.sql',
 'Migrations\\300_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\740_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3_PCD.sql',
 'Migrations\\840_ELCODATA_Update_sp__MaturityGateControl_2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\915_ELCODATA_spmg2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\BITE_index_report .sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_MOD_to_be_certified.sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_SB_certified.sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_Certification_List_of_SB_to_be_certified.sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_Export_the_Last_MoM.sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_Forecast_Date_History_for_MP.sql',
 'Migrations\\MAFU_UMO_Follow_up.sql',
 'Migrations\\RD2062_updateSP_sp_INSERT_ALERTS_FOR_RELEASED.sql'}

In [58]: [n for n in name if re.search(r'ELCODATA.*PCD', n, flags=re.I)]
Out[58]: ['Migrations\\740_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3_PCD.sql']
```

RegEx позволит наиболее гибко искать текст, например:

```
In [60]: pat = r'\\(300|915).*?_ELCODATA_'

In [61]: [n for n in name if re.search(pat, n)]
Out[61]:
['Migrations\\915_ELCODATA_spmg2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\300_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3.sql']
```

для простого поиска подстроки достаточно:

```
In [59]: [n for n in name if 'History' in n]
Out[59]: ['Migrations\\MAFU_Forecast_Date_History_for_MP.sql']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Также можно воспользоваться модулем [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) (спасибо [@jfs за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641416/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5/641422?noredirect=1#comment910573_641422)):

```
In [137]: fnmatch.filter(name, '*ELCODATA*')
Out[137]:
['Migrations\\740_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3_PCD.sql',
 'Migrations\\840_ELCODATA_Update_sp__MaturityGateControl_2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\915_ELCODATA_spmg2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\300_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3.sql']

In [139]: fnmatch.filter(name, '*\\[39]*ELCODATA*')
Out[139]:
['Migrations\\915_ELCODATA_spmg2to3.sql',
 'Migrations\\300_ELCODATA_sp_mg2to3.sql']
```

Comment: Чтобы glob синтаксис использовать, можно `fnmatch.filter()` вызвать.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо!! добавил в ответ...